# Not adding the library with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-library

I want to add a library to my project from GitHub, but I get this error.
Help me please

error--->>>

Failed to resolve: com.github.mejdi14:Flat-Dialog-Android:1.0.5

Show in Project Structure dialog

Show Details

Affected Modules: app

Comment: Did you add Jitpack.io as a repository, as is described in [the documentation for that library](https://github.com/mejdi14/Flat-Dialog-Android#installation)?

Comment: Yes
And I can't add any such library.
For example, I cannot add any of the libraries for design Android